# The Papapetrou transformation. Conditions to be satisfied to achieve requirements of transformation

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

I'm looking at the Papapetrou transformation in Ch. 6, $\S 52$ of Chandrasekhar's book. He cf's Ch. 2, $\S$11.

I understand Ch. 2, $\S$11. There he considers a coordinate transformation,

\begin{align*}
{x'}^1 = \phi (x^1,x^2)  \qquad \text{and}  \qquad  {x'}^2 = \psi (x^1,x^2)
\end{align*}

which will reduce the contravariant form of the line element

\begin{align*}
ds^2 = g^{11} (dx_1)^2 + 2 g^{12} dx_1 dx_2 + g^{22} (dx_2)^2
\end{align*}

to diagonal form with equal coefficients for $(dx_1)^2$ and $(dx_2)^2$. For a transformation to achieve this it is necessary and sufficient that

\begin{align*}
g^{'12} = g^{11} \phi_{,1} \psi_{,1} + 2 g^{12} (\phi_{,1} \psi_{,2} + \phi_{,2} \psi_{,1}) + g^{22} \phi_{,2} \psi_{,2} = 0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
g^{'11} - g^{'22} = g^{11} ({\phi_{,1}}^2 - {\psi_{,1}}^2) + 2 g^{12} (\phi_{,1} \phi_{,2} - \psi_{,1} \psi_{,2}) + g^{22} ({\phi_{,2}}^2 - {\psi_{,2}}^2)  = 0
\end{align*}

I get all of this.

In Ch. 6, $\S$52, (b) The  Papapetrou transformation, he is wanting to perform a coordinate transformation

\begin{align*}
(x^2,x^3) \rightarrow (\rho , z)
\end{align*}

such that

\begin{align*}
e^{2 \mu} [(dx_2)^2 + (dx_3)^2] \rightarrow f (\rho , z) [(d \rho)^2 + (dz)^2]
\end{align*}

Regarding the possibility of making such a coordinate transformation, he cf's Ch. 2 $\S$11. So I was thinking I should write

\begin{align*}
{x'}^2 = \rho (x^2,x^3)  \qquad \text{and}  \qquad  {x'}^3 = z (x^2,x^3)
\end{align*}

where $\rho$ and $z$ are to be chosen so that the metric remains in diagonal form and with equal coefficients for $(d \rho)^2$ and $(dz)^2$. For a transformation to achieve this it is necessary and sufficient that

\begin{align*}
g^{'23} = g^{22} \rho_{,2} z_{,2} + 2 g^{23} (\rho_{,2} z_{,3} + \rho_{,3} z_{,2}) + g^{33} \rho_{,3} z_{,3} = 0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
g^{'22} - g^{'33} = g^{22} ({\rho_{,2}}^2 - {z_{,2}}^2) + 2 g^{23} (\rho_{,2} \rho_{,3} - z_{,2} z_{,3}) + g^{33} ({\rho_{,3}}^2 - {z_{,3}}^2)  = 0
\end{align*}

As $g^{23} = 0$ and $g^{22} = g^{33}$, the first condition requires
\begin{align*}
\rho_{,2} z_{,2} + \rho_{,3} z_{,3} = 0
\end{align*}

As $g^{23} = 0$ and $g^{22} = g^{33}$, the second condition requires

\begin{align*}
{\rho_{,2}}^2 - {z_{,2}}^2 = - {\rho_{,3}}^2 + {z_{,3}}^2
\end{align*}

However, Chandrasekhar gets these conditions instead:

\begin{align*}
{\rho_{,2}}^2 + {z_{,2}}^2 & = {\rho_{,3}}^2 + {z_{,3}}^2
\nonumber \\
\rho_{,2} \rho_{,3} + z_{,2} z_{,3} & = 0
\end{align*}

How does Chandrasekhar arrive at these conditions?

Are my conditions not necessary and sufficient conditions for the transformation to achieve the stated requirements? Chandrasekhar notes that his conditions are satisfied by $\rho_{,2} = +z_{,3}$ and $\rho_{,3} = - z_{,2}$. I notice that my conditions are satisfied by these choices as well.